# Varieties receiving a morphism from projective space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Are any interesting family of smooth projective varieties that receive a surjective regular morphism (and maybe finite) from projective space? Now what we replace projective space by varieties constructed out of projective spaces, like product of projective space or projective bundles over projective spaces ...

Comment: If I have my terms right, the answer to the first question is the class of **unirational varieties**. I don't know about the second question though.

Comment: As @TabesBridges says: the first class you are looking for is that of unirational varieties. The second class as well, because a product of projective spaces (resp. projective bundle over projective space) is again unirational. (Actually, what do you mean by projective bundle over projective spaces?)

Comment: It seems, unirationals are those receiving rational dominant morphisms.  Maybe dominant is confusing but I meant dominant and regular morphisms. (It is surjective)